# $M_k:=\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n: x_k>x_{k+1}\}$ is open with respect to eucildean metric

Tags: general-topology

I consider the set

$$M_k:=\left \{(x_1,...,x_n)^T\in \mathbb{R}^n: x_k>x_{k+1}\right\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$$
for all $ k\in \{1,...,n-1\} $.

I tried to show that $ M_k $ is open with respect to $ \|.\|_2 $.

My idea was to chose the radius $ r:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot |x_k-x_{k+1}|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot (x_k-x_{k+1}) $ for every $ (x_1,...,x_n)^T\in M_k $. Let be $ (y_1,...,y_n)^T\in B_r((x_1,...,x_n)^T) $ arbitrary. So it applies
$$ r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot (x_k-x_{k+1})>\sqrt{\sum\limits_{l=1}^n |x_l-y_l|^2} $$
But here I have no idea how to estimate the right epression (sum) downwards to isolate $ y_k $ and $ y_{k+1} $ to get $ y_k>y_{k+1} $.

Or is there an easier way to show that $ M_k $ is open with respect to $ \|.\|_2 $?

Comment: Preimages of open sets via continuous functions are open. What can you say about continuity of function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x_1,...,x_n) = x_k - x_{k+1}$?

Comment: Which Preimage shall I consider?

Comment: Do you see what open set $U \subset \mathbb R$ to take, to get $f^{-1}[U] = M_k$?

Comment: No. This concept is quite new for me and to be honest I don't like it.

Comment: Do you see any connections with $M_k$ and $x_k - x_{k+1}$?

Comment: With $ x_k>x_{k+1} $ I get $ f((x_1,...,x_n)^T)=x_k-x_{k+1}>0 $ which means $ f((x_1,...,x_n)^T)\in ]0,\infty[ $.

Comment: Exactly, $M_k$ consists exactly of those points $(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $x_k-x_{k+1} > 0$ or equivalently, $f(x_1,...,x_n) > 0$. Hence $M_k = f^{-1}[ (0,\infty)]$. Since $(0,\infty)$ is open and $f$ is continuous (as a difference of projections for example), then $M_k = f^{-1}[(0,\infty)]$ is open.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

For $1\le k<n$ let $f_k(x_1,...,x_n)=x_k-x_{k+1}.$ Then $f_k$ is continuous so $M_k=f_k^{-1}(0,\infty)$ is open.

There are many ways to show $f_k$ is continuous. E.g. any projection $p_i(x_1,...,x_n)=x_i$ is continuous, so $p_k-p_{k+1}$ is continuous.

Comment: A projection $p_i$ is Lipschitz-continuous because if $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $x'=(x'_1,...,x'_n)$ then $|p_i(x)-p_i(x')|=|x_i-x'_i|\le \|x-x'\|.$